# phpredis errors Class Redis not found in Linux

Tags: php, linux, nginx, redis, phpredis

I met a weied problem when installing phpredis by

```
cd phpredis && ./configure && make && make install
```

after that, I add

```
extension=redis.so
```

into php.ini.

I can get an OK by running

```
php -r "if (new Redis() == true){ echo \"\r\n OK \r\n\"; }"
```

BUT when running http:127.0.0.1, nginx throw a error " Fatal error: Class 'Redis' not found in index.php"

```
<?php>
    $client = new Redis();
<?>
```

I guess this may be some problems related with environment...

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command line probably does not use the same php.ini file than the web server.
Use `phpinfo();` to know which configuration file is loaded in both cases and then declare your extension in the ini file used by your web server.

Comment: noooo... "Loaded Configuration File" idem with "php -i" and "phpinfo();"  And I see "redis" section with "Redis Version" 3 below...

Comment: Sorry, I was drunk, with $r = new \Redis(); (with a backslash) it works.  Probably looking the another error line with setOption(Redis::OPT_PREFIX...

Comment: I fixed uncommenting in /etc/php/conf.d/igbinary.ini and /etc/php/conf.d/redis.ini

Comment: OMG, thank you so much. I fell so stupid.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue minutes ago, and I solved it restarting the server, this way the server refresh *.ini files

Comment: restarting apache did the job

Comment: Restarting apache did the job for me as well

Answer (score 0):

If you're using composer and get the error "Class Redis not found" try put a backslash before the name class. Like this:

```
<?php
    $client = new \Redis();
<?
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).