# I have clone one of the project from github and after running on localhost I am getting this error - Class 'Redis' not found

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redis, linux-mint

Currently, I am using Codeigniter for my project and have been using it on the Linux-mint operating system.

My Error looks like this -

```
    An uncaught Exception was encountered
    Type: Error

    Message: Class 'Redis' not found

    Filename: /opt/lampp/htdocs/test-pro/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_redis_driver.php

    Line Number: 178

    Backtrace:

    File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/test-pro/application/helpers/lang_helper.php
    Line: 64
    Function: library

    File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/test-pro/application/controllers/form/login.php
    Line: 8
    Function: __construct

    File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/test-pro/index.php
    Line: 315
    Function: require_once
```

Can someone please help me to get out of this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this post helps you [phpredis errors Class Redis not found in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858704/phpredis-errors-class-redis-not-found-in-linux)

Or trying to clone again